# Logic for Lexicographical numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm

For an integer n,we have to return 1 to n in lexicographical order. Below is the code for it.I understand the code but what is the logic behind it?

For example:given 13, return: [1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

```
class Solution {
    public:
        vector<int> lexicalOrder(int n) {
            vector<int> result(n);
            int curr = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                result[i] = curr;
                if (curr * 10 <= n) {
                    curr *= 10;
                } else if (curr % 10 != 9 && curr + 1 <= n) {
                    curr += 1;
                } else {
                    while((curr / 10) % 10 == 9) {
                        curr /= 10;
                    }
                    curr = curr / 10 + 1;
                }
            }
            return result;

        }
    };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I understand the code" if you don't understand the logic? I don't see how you can separate them.

Comment: @rici I mean if n=13. I can see how we get [1,10,11,12,13,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], i.e. how it follows the if else conditions but what is the algorithm used here?For example if we want to get pow(x,n) the logic that can used is (if n is even then pow(x,n/2), if n is odd pow(x,n-1), if n  is 0 , then it is 1).

Comment: The if-else conditions *are* the logic. What is the next number after `c` in lexicographic order? If you can add a 0, do that. If not, if the last digit is not 9, increment it. Otherwise, delete the last digit.

Comment: @rici, got it!!!Thanks.